# MongoDB push or update data

Tags: mongodb, express, routes

how to add them in the absence of data MongoDB, and update them if available. Username: String and rate: Number comes in the request body.

```
placeRoutes.route('/:id/add').post(async function (req, res) {
try {
const { id } = req.params;
Place.findByIdAndUpdate(
  id,
  {
    $push: {
      rating: req.body,
    },
    $set: {'rating.$.username': req.body}
  },
  { new: true, upsert: true },
  function (err, result) {
    if (err) return res.send(err);
    res.send(result);
  }
);
} catch (error) {
   res.status(500).send('Something went wrong');
 }
});
```

As a result, I add any data, but if there is data on the username key, I need to update the value of the rate field.
As a result, my data is not updated, I will be grateful for any help

Comment: Could you elaborate your question further? Like what issue you're facing, what is the end product you want to achieve.